# Python2 : How to speed up Queue.get with timeout?

Tags: python, multithreading, timeout, queue

I'm trying to write a fast event system for multiples threads using Queues.
Each Thread has a stdin and wait for this one to be filled.

So main part of my thread is like that :

```
class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.stdin = Queue.Queue()
        # Some code here

    def run(self):
        while True:
             try:
                 order = self.stdin.get(block=True,timeout=5)
                 if self.do(order) is False:
                     break
             except Queue.Empty:
                 pass

    def do(self,order):
        if order["txt"] == "quit":
            return False
        deltaTime = time.time() - order["time"]
        print("Message : "+str(order["txt"])+", DeltaTime : "+str(deltaTime))
        # Some code here
```

I would like to do fast multimedia opperations so I need a realy reactive system, but when I do some litle benchmark I got 50 ms of latence juste with that (on a 2.4 GHz Intel i7 processor)

This is my benchmark code :

```
thread = MyThread()
thread.start()
thread.stdin.put({"txt": "test1", "time": time.time()})
time.sleep(1)
thread.stdin.put({"txt": "test2", "time": time.time()})
time.sleep(1)
thread.stdin.put({"txt": "test3", "time": time.time()})
time.sleep(1)
thread.stdin.put({"txt": "quit", "time": time.time()})
thread.join()
print("END")
```

And finaly I got that :

```
Message : test1, DeltaTime : 0.00104689598083
Message : test2, DeltaTime : 0.0151479244232
Message : test3, DeltaTime : 0.0292360782623
END
```

This is about 20 ms but with all the program it's far to much for a real time application !
Now when I try without the timeout it's much better :

```
Message : test1, DeltaTime : 6.69956207275e-05
Message : test2, DeltaTime : 5.22136688232e-05
Message : test3, DeltaTime : 5.79357147217e-05
END
```

Is there any solution to speed up the Queue.get with keeping the timeout ?

Thanks !

Comment: Why do you need the timeout? In your example, you're just ignoring the timeout and calling `get` again, anyway.

Comment: What OS? How good is your computer? I'm getting significantly different timings.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your attention. @dano : Indeed I've written this example in order to keep the code easy to read. In fact, I use the timeout for asking my arduino if some sensors have changed and to perform some little tasks.
I was thinking of making a thread wait for a timeout an put an element to my Queue for making my threads wake up, but it's kind of dirty, isn't it ?

Comment: Hi @Veedrac, **uname -a** : Linux ******* 3.16.3-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Sep 17 21:54:13 CEST 2014 x86_64 GNU/Linux (Archlinux), I've got an SSD disk and DDR3 memory so it's a good computer.

Comment: @Olivier Then your timings confuse me. Sorry :(